# ALTER COLUMN command TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was quite confused on why in the preperation for the microsoft 70-461 exam it says this:

```
Create tables without using the built in tools; ALTER; DROP; ALTER COLUMN; CREATE
```

What exactly does `ALTER COLUMN` mean? I do not recall that being a statement or command could anybody please explain this for me. Thanks :)

Comment: It's used with `alter table`. Like - `alter table alter column col int`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: ALTER COLUMN is like a sub command of ALTER command. When you want to change the definition of a column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use it as part of an `alter table` statement to change a column definition:

```
alter table t1
alter column c1 varchar(50) not null
```

It will give an error without the `alter table` piece.